# UserId and UserName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have to use UserId in a AdminUsers.aspx page ( to manage users activation and unLocking accounts ) . I've planned to save UserId as gridview DataKey . 
but the problem is that I don't know if userId is ok to be saved in viewstate and be exposed to users . is there any security issue with UserId ?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like UserID is just the primary key to your User table. As such, I don't see any security issue. Knowledge of an internal primary key shouldn't help unauthorized access.

A lot of databases use Identity (int) primary keys. If the system was designed in such a way that damage could be done via primary key, then a malicious user could just keep trying numbers.

EDIT: Just realized that this is tagged asp.net-membership, so I presume that UserID is the GUID that membership uses. I still don't see this as a security issue. It's just a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx), then there's little security risk because each user has their own session.

Comment: No , I want to List All users in a gridview so admin could manage them , not just for currently logged in user

Answer (score 0):

You can save the UserID in database in encrypted format. Now in the gridview you can have a hidden label. on edit of a specific row you can access the hidden userID and finally decrypt it....